# Can't apply orderbydescending lambda

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have a very simple lambda expression , but there is something wrong with it , I am unable to chose a field upon which I would want to use orderbydesc

```
vRepository.Visitors.Select(v=>v.VisitorNumber).OrderBy(o=>o.
```

in the options that i recieve after i press "o" , I do not see the fields of the Visitor table.

The visitors are of type IQueryable

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting only `VisitorName` in your Select statement, that is why you can't see rest of the fields. You should select the field after ordering like:

```
vRepository.Visitors.OrderBy(o=>o.YourField).Select(v=>v.VisitorNumber)
```

If as per your title you want to OrderByDescending then use [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx) instead of `OrderBy`.

```
vRepository.Visitors.OrderByDescending(o=> o.YourField).Select(v=>v.VisitorNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks habib. You saved me  a lot of hassle .